# C# Manipulação de Imagem e PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

Gostaria de saber se há um jeito de transformar várias imagens, em um único arquivo PDF. 
Na minha aplicação eu Já estou puxando o endereço delas.

Comment: Da uma olhda neste link --> http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 e neste outro --> http://weblogs.asp.net/andrenobre/gerando-arquivos-pdf-com-net-e-itextsharp

Comment: Se for opção realizar a chamada a uma aplicação externa, veja sobre `ImageMagick` e `PDFTK`. São muito fácil de utilizar, fazem muito bem o serviço, e executar aplicativos externos em C# é muito simples. Claro que nem sempre é opção ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o [iTextSharp 4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL/), pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 20, 20, 20, 20);
string PDFOutput = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream(PDFOutput, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));

Doc.Open();

string Folder = "C:\\Diretorio\\das\\Imagens";
foreach (string F in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.jpg")) 
{
    Doc.NewPage();
    Doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Jpeg(new Uri(new FileInfo(F).FullName)));
}

Doc.Close();
```

[Tirei a resposta daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109257/1314276).